# Prime ideals of a quotient ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, ideals

I  want to prove that

If R  is any ring  and  I be an ideal, then an ideal P containing I is a prime ideal of R   iff   P/I is prime ideal of R /I.

Could you check my proof ?

Proof:  Let P be a prime ideal  .   To prove first P/I is prime ideal of  R/I. Let $ (a+I), (b+I) \in R/I$  such that
$(a+I)( b+I) \in P/I$. Then  $ab+I \in P/I$. It implies  $ab \in P$.

As P is prime,  $a \in P$ or $b \in P \implies a +I \in P/I$ or $b+I\in P/I$

Hence $P/I$ is prime.

Conversely,  let $P/I$ be a prime ideal of $R/I$. let us prove that $P$ is prime ideal of  $R$ .     Let $a,b \in R$ such that  $ab \in P$ then
  $ab+I \in P/I \implies ( a+I)(b+I) \in P/I$.

As  $P/I$ is prime, $a+I \in P/I$  or $b+I \in P/I \implies  a \in P$ or $b \in P$ .

Comment: Sounds correct. Instead of a two-part proof, you could think of  equivalence statements.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the standard way of proving this: By some of these isomorphism theorems, we have $(R/I)/(P/I) \cong R/P$. This immediately gives you all you need.

Comment: Usually, it's called the third isomorphism theorem.